# Weitzenböck Identity

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weitzenb%C3%B6ck_identity), the Weitzenböck formula asserts
$$
{\displaystyle \Delta '-\Delta =A},
$$
where $A$ is a linear operator of order zero involving only the curvature, and $\Delta'$ and $\Delta$ are the Bochner and form Laplacian, respectively.

Wikipedia then continues that the precise form of $A$ is
$$
{\displaystyle A={\frac {1}{2}}\langle \text{R}(\theta ,\theta )\#,\#\rangle +\operatorname {Ric} (\theta ,\#),}
$$
where

- $\text{R}$ is the Riemann curvature tensor,
- $\text{Ric}$ is the Ricci tensor,
- ${\displaystyle \theta :T^{*}M\otimes \Omega ^{p}M\rightarrow \Omega ^{p+1}M}$ is the map that takes the wedge product of a $1$-form and $p$-form and gives a $(p+1)$-form,
- ${\displaystyle \#:\Omega ^{p+1}M\rightarrow T^{*}M\otimes \Omega ^{p}M}$ is the universal derivation inverse to $θ$ on $1$-forms.

How exactly is this formula supposed to be read? That is, how would I evaluate $A$ on a $p$-form?

Any help would be much appreciated.